# X and Y inputs in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I am new to LabVIEW and I am trying to read a code written in LabVIEW. The block diagram is this: [image: block diagram]

This is the program to input x and y functions into the voltage input. It is meant to give an input voltage in different forms (sine, heartshape , etc.) into the fast-steering mirror or galvano mirror x and y axises.

x and y function controls are for inputting a formula for a function, and then we use "evaluation single value" function to input into a daq assistant.

I understand that `{ 2*(|-Mpi|)/N }*i + -Mpi*pi` goes into the x value. However, I dont understand why we use this kind of formula. Why we need to assign a negative value and then do the absolute value of -M*pi. Also, I don`t understand why we need to divide to N and then multiply by i. And finally, why need to add -Mpi again? If you provide any hints about this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Miscellaneous    it is meant to give an input voltage in different forms (sine, heartshape , etc.) into the fast-steering mirror or galvano mirror x and y axises.   I understand that  { 2*(|-M*pi|)/N }*i   +   -M*pi*pi goes into the x value, but why this form... I dont understand

Comment: I don't know anything about the details, but I would suggest looking at actual values to understand what different parts of the formula do. You could output them as arrays from the loop or you could place a chart inside the loop or as probes. Presumably the behavior is specific to how your setup works. A couple of specific points, though: Multiplying by -1 does not mean the value is negative. It might have started negative and then the ABS won't change it. Dividing by N and multiplying by i gives you the progress in a scale of 0-1 (although it's off by 1, so you'll never get to 1).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a complicated way to write the code/formula. Given what the code looks like (unnecessary wire bends, duplicate loop-input-tunnels, hidden wires, unnecessary coercion dots, failure to use appropriate built-in 'negate' function) not much care has been given in writing it. So while it probably yields the correct results you should not expect it to do so in the most readable way.

To answer you specific questions:

*Why we need to assign a negative value and then do the absolute value*

We don't. We can just move the negation immediately before the last addition or change that to a subtraction:
`{ 2*(|Mpi|)/N }*i - Mpi*pi`
And as @yair pointed out: We are not assigning a value here, we are basically flipping the sign of whatever value the user entered.

*Why we need to divide to N and then multiply by i*

This gives you a fraction between 0 and 1, no matter how many steps you do in your for-loop. Think of `N` as a sampling rate. I.e. your mirrors will always do the same movement, but a larger N just produces more steps in between.

*Why need to add -Mpi again*

I would strongly assume this is some kind of quick-and-dirty workaround for a bug that has not been fixed properly. Looking at the code it seems this `+Mpi*pi` has been added later on in the development process. And while I don't know what the expected values are I would believe that multiplying only one of the summands by Pi is probably wrong.